# how to add all of these values in a python dictionary

Tags: python

last one for the night, want to see what clever ways there are with python to add all of the 'count' values from the following type of dictionary:

```
{0: {'count': 1000}, 1: {'count': 2000}}
```

so the end result should be an int value of 3000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> x = {0: {'count': 1000}, 1: {'count': 2000}}
>>> sum(v['count'] for v in x.values()) 
3000
```

Comment: Use .itervalues() to save some memory overhead, since .values() builds a new list for the values.

Answer (score 4):

A shorter one:

```
sum(d[k]['count'] for k in d)
```

Comment: It saves a few characters, but it's slower since you have to look up each key, instead of iterating over the values directly.

Comment: Well technically, for the example it's 5% faster :) But you're right, for large dicts it's about 15% slower.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(i['count'] for i in d.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using reduction in python?

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [v['count'] for v in a.values()])
```